# Compare Frequencies

Tags: regression, logistic, chi-squared-test, histogram, frequency

I have a continuous predictor variable that I have divided into bins (at 0%, 0 to 25%, ...).  For each of these bins, I have shown you the histogram below of Number of Companies that are in that range and the number of bankruptcies.

You'd expect bankruptcies to rise as asset growth reaches 100% (and also when asset growth is near 0%).  An overall chi-square test of independence on these bins revealed that bankruptcies and asset growth% bins are not independent.

How do I prove that higher (**and/or** lower) asset growth are strongly related to bankruptcies?  Of course, the hit rate for asset growth% is the highest.

I used Chi-Sq on each bin (df=1) and expected bankruptcy = (avg hit rate) x bin size but this may be incorrect.  Do I perform univariate logistic regression 6 times and compare model results?  (all prob are=0 for the asset growth=100% bin using LR/glmfit).  I use **MATLAB**.

[image: Histogram for Number of Companies & Bankruptcies over asset growth %]

Comment: (1) logistic regression with k-1 dummy variables for your k bins. (2) there are number of alternative ways to include non-linear relationships in logistic regression. Restricted cubic splines being one. But dummy variables should be a reasonable start

Comment: (3) I'd plot proportions rather than counts.